# How to count number of corresponding values of a JSON across 2 tables and map it to its key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find anything. I have two tables:

[image: Questions and Responses Tables]

Here's the result I'm going for:
[image]

In this scenario, question_id links the Questions and Responses table.

**For the result:**

If question_type = multiple_choice, it counts the number of responses corresponding to each multiple choice option and stores it in a JSON under mcq_response.

Meanwhile, if question type = text_input, it stores all the responses in a comma-separated string under text_response.

**My work so far:**

```
 SELECT Questions.*, IF(Questions.question_type = "text_input", GROUP_CONCAT(Responses.question_response), null) as text_response 
 FROM Questions  
 LEFT JOIN Responses
 ON (Questions.question_id = Responses.response_id)
 group by Questions.question_id
```

This yields the text response column perfectly, and I can use it in my application.

However, I can't begin to wrap my head around how to approach the mcq_response column, specifically the mapping between the mcq_choices and number of responses for each key in the JSON. Any help/direction here would be much appreciated.

The database design is flexible, so I can always change it to make the solution easier. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make it clear, the end goal is to display all responses under its corresponding question, and if its an MCQ, it simply displays the count of each option next to the option itself. If the work I've done so far is stupid, please call it out since I'm new to all this.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4RTBJ6uS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the choices into a separate table. You can use the following columns:

`question_id | option | value`

In that way, you can simply save the `option` in the results table and query like this:

```
select 
        q.question_id, q.question, q.question_type,
        case when q.question_type == 'multiple_choice' then mcq.value
            else r.question_response end as response
from Questions q
    join Responses r on q.question_id = r.question_id
    left join MCQ mcq on mcq.question_id = r.question_id 
        and r.question_response = mcq.option
```

Comment: Going to go with something like this. Thanks so much!